# Meta description Error

Tags: seo

I'm a newbie in joomla CMS. I have this problem:
even if in Meta Description of the artiche there's the correct description, I notice that meta description tag of resulting page is like that:

[widgetkit id="30" name="Home specializzazioni"]   Visita anche Laserdermatologia.net ...

what's happening? why shortcode is included in meta description?
and more, adding ?adasasdasdasd or something like that, page refreshes and meta description is updated to correct value, but, it comes back to wrong value if I remove ?asdasdadsasd...I tried with different browser (that I never used with this site, so no cache client), and the problem still remains. Even google in SERP shows this wrong description. 
In my last try, I cleared cache from System in Joomla, but nothing changes. 
Please help me!

Comment: Please don't use the answers section to provide updates regarding your issue or open up a conversation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the meta description in the Menu Item - This is pulling the meta description from the content of the page.

In the menu item, go to the 'Meta Data' tab, and add your information there.

Edit: In sh404sef go to the Titles and Meta page and add your meta descriptions for each page in there - this should then display correctly. Let me know how you get on. :)

Regards
D

Comment: I tried, but not fix the problem :(
If I set what you say, nothing change.
If I set the description into sh404SEF->Main CP->title and metas, not changes :(
is there anything set? I used sh404SEF to handle custom URLs of pages...it could be the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing this is SH404SEF related. I've updated my answer above.